# How do I change the a single image in the lottie json file

Tags: android, lottie

I have made an animation by adobe after effects and exported `JSON` file with images and it works, as I have put photos from the assets folder.

I want to change one of the images which are in the `JSON` file

```
"assets": [
 {
  "id": "image_0",
  "w": 960,
  "h": 540,
  "u": "images/",
  "p": "img_0.png"
}
```

This is the piece of the `JSON` file that has the id I don't know how to change it or to change the name or to set images programmatically

In other words I want to change a specific image that I choose from my java code and put another image for example change the shirt image.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found the Answer after some research simply use this function

```
lottieAnimationView.updateBitmap("the id of the image which is found in the json file",thebitmap);
```

Comment: I prefer to use : `lottieAnimationView.setAnimation(R.raw.your_animated_image)`

Comment: lottieAnimationView.setAnimation(R.raw.your_animated_image) is not working as it fallbacks to onAnimationCancel() instead of onAnimationEnd()

Answer (score 3):

After doing much research, I've found there are 2 ways to change images in animation Lotte json.

1. As @Nour Ahmed mentioned, `updateBitmap()` is the correct way. However, there is a subtle reminder, you have to make sure the `LottieAnimationView` was completely inflated and visible. Mostly case you update the image in `onCreate()`, it doesn't work. Thus, make a trick of delaying a few milliseconds:

   ```
   // Bug Lottie @@.
   lavChest.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

         // UPDATE 2020 AUG 07.
         // Some devices require you to set image Assets folder again.
         lavChest.setImageAssetsFolder("aep/reward/images");

         lavChest.updateBitmap("image_6", bmReward);
         lavChest.updateBitmap("image_2", bmNo);
         lavChest.updateBitmap("image_4", bmCategory);

         lavChest.playAnimation();
      }
   }, 500);
   ```
2. The second way is using `setImageAssetDelegate()`, it only works once, though.

   ```
   lavChest.setImageAssetDelegate(new ImageAssetDelegate() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Bitmap fetchBitmap(LottieImageAsset asset) {

                switch (asset.getId()) {
                    case "image_6":
                        return bmReward;

                    case "image_2":
                        return bmNo;

                    case "image_4":
                        return bmCategory;

                    default:
                        AssetManager am = activity.getAssets();
                        try {
                            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(am.open("aep/" + asset.getDirName() + asset.getFileName()));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return null;
                        }
                }
            }
        });

   lavChest.playAnimation();
   ```

Despite closing the screen containing your `LottieAnimationView`, the images are still kept in Lottie cache. There is no proper way to interfere with this cache unless you close the app.

**Conclusion:**

- Use `setImageAssetDelegate()` to update images **the first time**.
- Use **updateBitmap()** to update images **next times**. Notice, the `LottieAnimationView` needs **completely** visible.

Answer (score 1):

@Nguyen Tan Dat the Answer solve my doubt, Thanks

```
   lavChest.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        lavChest.updateBitmap("image_6", bmReward);
        lavChest.updateBitmap("image_2", bmNo);
        lavChest.updateBitmap("image_4", bmCategory);

        lavChest.playAnimation();
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the json file, make your changes and put those changes in your json file again. Though you will not be able to do any 
`write/update`
 in your json file if it's stored in assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

**updateBitmap** should execute after **setComposition**。because **setComposition** method will execute setImageDrawable(null)。this will recycle bitmaps